# How to create cascading JFrames from the center of the screen?

Tags: java

So, I have a main JFrame that given a String input creates a solution and displays it in another JFrame, and for every input it gets, it creates a new JFrame.

The main JFrame is in the top left, and by using setLocationRelativeTo(null) I can create the solution JFrame in the center of the screen.

Problem is, when it creates a new solution, it completely hides the one before. So I tried to use setLocationByPlatform(true), but now the new JFrames are cascading from the main JFrame, and are not in the center anymore.

How can I have cascading JFrames start from the center of the screen?

Comment: You need to use setLocation on the newly created frame based on the previous frames position. There's also a public static Frame[] getFrames() in Frame that might help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Cascade Implementation

```java
public class CascadeExample {
    // Simple cascade
    public static void cascade(JFrame parent, JFrame child, int moveX, int moveY) {
        child.setX(parent.getX() + moveX);
        child.setY(parent.getY() + moveY);
    }

    // Multiplied cascade
    // 'Cascade the nth frame'
    public static void cascade(JFrame parent, JFrame child, int moveX, int moveY, int n) {
        cascade(parent, child, moveX * n, moveY * n);
    }
}
```

---

### Theoretical Usage

```java
// Cascade frames by the order they are placed in the array
static void cascadeAll(JFrame[] frames, int moveX, int moveY) {
    for (int i = 1; i < frames.length; i++) {
        CascadeExample.cascade(frames[i - 1], frames[i], moveX, moveY);
    }
}
```

---

If any correction or clarification is needed. Feel free to notify me!

Comment: I'm happy to help